# Pytest: When to use with pytest.raises vs xfail

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest

I have a method which is expected to raise an exception when an incorrect format of input is provided. I am wondering which is the correct way to test, when an incorrect input is supplied mark the test as `xfail` or actually test it `with pytest.raises` to see the actual exception is raised.

Answer (score 2):

The [pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/assert.html) on this say:

> Using pytest.raises() is likely to be better for cases where you are
> testing exceptions your own code is deliberately raising, whereas
> using @pytest.mark.xfail with a check function is probably better for
> something like documenting unfixed bugs (where the test describes what
> “should” happen) or bugs in dependencies.

So for exceptions raised on invalid formats this suggests the use of `pytest.raises`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xfail` , if you expect the function to raise an exception.

But there may be cases of exceptions other than incorrect format, where you want to consider them as failure.

Then you can use "raises" parameter as shown below in `xfail`

```
@pytest.mark.xfail(raises=YourFormatExceptionType)
```

After this any other exception other than the one specified in `raises`, will be considered as a regular failure.

You can pass a single exception or a tuple of exceptions to `raises` in the above function.

Related documentation:

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/skipping.html#raises-parameter